# Insert 2 records with Excel VBA into Access using ADODB with FK

Tags: excel, vba, database, ms-access

I'm setting up a small multi user app in Excel to use Access as the database layer. The only problem I've come across is how to insert two records in two tables where record 1 ID is the FK in the record 2 table.

I've been reading and testing with using DMax and last modified functions, but I'm not so sure it would work properly in a multi user (up to 5 users) environment. Also, deletions would have an impact on these two functions.

Is there a way to do this? The workaround would be to create the first record, and then select it on the refreshed UI in Excel and trigger the creation (insert) of the second record. Or, we could rely on another UUID created when the first record is inserted and then look that up. I'm not sure this would be watertight though.

---EDIT---

```vb
Sub InsertRecordAndGetID()
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim newRecordID As Long
    
    ' Set up the connection string to the Access database
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=My\db\location\db.accdb;"
    
    ' Define the SQL statement for inserting the record
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO employee (EmployeeName, EmployeeSurname) VALUES ('SomeName', 'SomeSurname');"
    
    ' Execute the SQL statement
    conn.Execute strSQL
    
    ' Retrieve the ID of the last inserted record using @@IDENTITY()
    strSQL = "SELECT @@IDENTITY AS NewID;"
    Set rs = conn.Execute(strSQL)
    newRecordID = rs.Fields("NewID").Value
    
    ' Close the connection
    rs.Close
    conn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "The ID of the last inserted record is: " & newRecordID
End Sub
```

I've tried with the @@IDENTITY and it seems to be working ok. The code above returns the ID as expected.

Just for reference: I've tried doing it in one call, but MS Access doesn't support it. I also found out I can't use scope_identity.

---END EDIT---

Thank you.
seba

Comment: Previously here:  https://www.google.com/search?q=Excel+vBA+ADO+get+id+for+inserted+access+record+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: And I have to ask why use Excel as GUI for Access?

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you for the link. I've tried some of the options before, my problem was I haven't translated some code to vba correctly.

Comment: @June7 there's a lot of legacy functionality that binds us to Excel currently, so the db port was the first thing on the list.